# Can't read large XML file from PHP

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I have a huge XML file (114 KB/1719 lines; see the error message below why I say *huge*) and I try to read it as I have done with two similar files before.

The other two files load normally and are of comparable size the only difference being that the file in question contains Arabic text. So here is the PHP code:

```
$doc3 = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$doc3->load($masternumber.'.xml');
```

And the error is:

> Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: Excessive depth in document: 256 use XML_PARSE_HUGE option in file: ...

Then `$doc3` doesn't load the file. So I modified the code:

```
$doc3->load($masternumber.'.xml', "LIBXML_PARSEHUGE");
```

And I end-up with another warrning:

> Warning: DOMDocument::load() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in...

`$doc3` is empty again.

What is wrong with it? The other files contain the same text in other languages and load properly but not this one? I am using PHP 5.3.9.

Comment: it's a constant: `$doc3->load($masternumber.'.xml', LIBXML_PARSEHUGE);`

Comment: on a sidenote: DOMDocument will discard anything you put in the ctor when you use any of the load* methods and use whatever it finds in the XML prolog, so new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8') is pointless.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a constant, not a string.

```
$doc3->load($masternumber.'.xml', LIBXML_PARSEHUGE);
```

See the [`DOMDocument::load()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php) documentation for complete details.  The second parameter is a long integer representing the selected options from the [list of constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php).

Incidentally, if you need multiple options for any reason, it is done by combining them with the bitwise OR operator `|`

```
// Multiple options  OR'd together...
// Just FYI, not specific to your situation...
$doc3->load($masternumber.'.xml', LIBXML_PARSEHUGE|LIBXML_NSCLEAN);
```

Comment: +1 for "Use a constant, not a string". -1 for the rest of the answer. -1 for no external references. -1 for not explaining why a "long" is required rather than a "string".  Poor show.

Comment: @salathe Given that the OP already knew to use LIBXML_PARSEHUGE, though incorrectly, I assumed the OP already found the relevant documentation but misunderstood it.

Comment: I'll assume he read the error message and came straight here to be spoon fed.